# How to get the url of a file uploaded using fileCreate?

Tags: php, graphql, shopify

Have followed the example mutator as shown in the [documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-graphql/2023-04/mutations/filecreate)

```
    $query = <<<QUERY
  mutation fileCreate(\$files: [FileCreateInput!]!) {
    fileCreate(files: \$files) {
      files {
        alt
        createdAt
      }
      userErrors {
        field
        message
      }
    }
  }
QUERY;
```

This is just returning the createdAt time that the file was uploaded. How do I get the cdn url of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires a two-step approach. The first is to amend the original mutation to retrieve the generated file id from shopify:

```
    $query = <<<QUERY
  mutation fileCreate(\$files: [FileCreateInput!]!) {
    fileCreate(files: \$files) {
      files {
        alt
        createdAt
        ... on GenericFile {
          id
        }
        ... on MediaImage {
          id
        }
        ... on Video {
          id
        }
      }
      userErrors {
        field
        message
      }
    }
  }
QUERY;
```

This will return an id similar to `gid://shopify/MediaImage/123456789012345`

Once the file has been uploaded we need to call a `files` query with our ID:

```
    $getFileQuery = <<<QUERY
query {
    files(first: 1, query: "id:{{ id }}") {
      edges {
        node {
          fileStatus
          ... on MediaImage {
            image {
              url
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
}
QUERY;
```

When you upload a file Shopify has to process it so the status is "PROCESSING" and you won't get the url out until it's finished. So I wrap the query function in a do/while loop:

```
//Ping shopify for the image. Make sure it has finished being processed.
$process = false;
do {
    //Find my file by id
    $response = $api->query(["query" => str_replace('{{ id }}', str_replace('gid://shopify/MediaImage/', '', $data['data']['fileCreate']['files'][0]['id']), $getFileQuery)]);
    $data = $response->getDecodedBody();

    //File still processing. Wait a moment and try again.
    if (
        !array_key_exists(0, $data['data']['files']['edges']) || 
        $data['data']['files']['edges'][0]['node']['fileStatus'] != 'READY'
    ) {
        sleep(1);
        continue;
    }

    //Found our file. Extract the image url
    $newFileName = $data['data']['files']['edges'][0]['node']['image']['url'];
    $process = true; //Break the loop.
} while (!$process);
//Use $newFileName to take over the world.
```

Once Shopify has finished processing the file it sets the status as "READY" so you can grab the file url.